# C# List.Clear() method not getting correct response

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, mapping, automapper

I am trying to map the below class to a destination class using the below code. Here trying to map Employee class to

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var emp = new List<Employee>()
            {
                new Employee()
                {
                    FirstName = "Test",
                    LastName = "Performance",
                    ID="1",
                    Availabities = new List<Availability>()
                    {
                        new Availability()
                        {
                            BeginDate = DateTime.Now,
                            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)
                        }
                    }
                 },
                 new Employee()
                 {
                     FirstName = "Test1",
                     LastName = "Performance1",
                     ID="2",
                     Availabities = new List<Availability>()
                    {
                        new Availability()
                        {
                            BeginDate = DateTime.Now,
                            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(10)
                        }
                     }
                 },
                  new Employee()
                 {
                     FirstName = "Test123",
                     LastName = "Performance1",
                     ID="3",
                     Availabities = new List<Availability>()
                    {
                        new Availability()
                        {
                            BeginDate = DateTime.Now,
                            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(5)
                        },
                        new Availability()
                        {
                            BeginDate = DateTime.Now,
                            EndDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3)
                        }
                     }
                 }
            };
```

Here is the destination object mapping, here the Employee to be mapped with EmployeeDest.

```
            List<AvailabilityDest> empAvailabilitiesDest = new List<AvailabilityDest>();

            var results = new List<EmployeeDest>();

            foreach (var token in emp)
            {
                empAvailabilitiesDest.Clear();

                foreach (var item in token.Availabities)
                {
                    
                    var empAvailability = new AvailabilityDest
                    {
                        BeginDateDest = item.BeginDate,
                        EndDateDest = item.EndDate,
                    };
                        empAvailabilitiesDest.Add(empAvailability);
                }
                var employee = new EmployeeDest
                {
                    FirstNameDest = token.FirstName,
                    LastNameDest = token.LastName,
                   IDDest =token.ID,
                    AvailabitiesDest = empAvailabilitiesDest
                };
                results.Add(employee);
               
            }
            Console.WriteLine(results);
        }
```

Here the `empAvailabilitiesDest.Clear()` is not clearing the list and the `availabilityDest` is getting increased with each iteration.

I am missing something here .

2. How can I optimize the code here to get a better performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Problem in your code**

```
        var employee = new EmployeeDest
        {
            FirstNameDest = token.FirstName,
            LastNameDest = token.LastName,
            IDDest = token.ID,
            AvailabitiesDest = empAvailabilitiesDest // This is problematic code
        };
```

Due to above code, every empolyee.AvailabitiesDest will reference to the same object because it is not a primitive type variable.
You have to assign a copy of the object to employee.AvailabitiesDest,

```
        var employee = new EmployeeDest
        {
            FirstNameDest = token.FirstName,
            LastNameDest = token.LastName,
            IDDest = token.ID,
            AvailabitiesDest = new List<AvailabilityDest>(empAvailabilitiesDest)
        };
```

**2. Simplifying code**

Use Linq.

```
        results = emp.Select(token => new EmployeeDest
        {
            FirstNameDest = token.FirstName,
            LastNameDest = token.LastName,
            IDDest = token.ID,
            AvailabitiesDest = token.Availabities.Select(item => new AvailabilityDest
            {
                BeginDateDest = item.BeginDate,
                EndDateDest = item.EndDate,
            }).ToList()
        }).ToList();
```

Or use AutoMapper

```
    var mapper = new Mapper(new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.CreateMap<Employee, EmployeeDest>()
            .ForMember(x => x.FirstNameDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
            .ForMember(x => x.LastNameDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
            .ForMember(x => x.IDDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.ID))
            .ForMember(x=> x.AvailabitiesDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Availabities));
        cfg.CreateMap<Availability, AvailabilityDest>()
            .ForMember(x => x.BeginDateDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.BeginDate))
            .ForMember(x => x.EndDateDest, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.EndDate));
    }));

    var results = mapper.Map<List<EmployeeDest>>(emp);
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation of the issue with the existing code. The Solution works fine,

Answer (score 2):

Presumably the real problem here is that all your employee objects are sharing the *same* list; it doesn't matter whether you clear it, add things, etc: if there's one list and it is shared between all the employees, then changes to that list will show against *every* employee, and it will appear incorrect.

Presumably, you really just want to move the list creation to *inside* the `foreach` per employee:

```cs
var results = new List<EmployeeDest>();
foreach (var token in emp)
{
    List<AvailabilityDest> empAvailabilitiesDest = new List<AvailabilityDest>
();
    // your previous code unchanged
}
```

Comment: yes , this will work, Infact this(list creation inside loop) was my first code, and due to performance issue the list creation part i have moved outside and tried the clear() method. Is there any better way i can map with performance improvemant

Comment: @jubi it is impossible to opine on performance things without detailed performance analysis; I doubt that the list creation is a hugely relevant factor

Comment: Can we simplify this with automapper.?

Comment: @jubi not significantly, but feel free to try